# Moving the content (data) from one DIV to other DIV

Tags: html, css

It's there any method that I can use for moving the content between DIVs without the jQuery or JavaScript ?

Example:

```
<div id="1">firstDiv</div>
<div id="2">secondDiv</div>
```

Result:

```
in DIV with id = 1 will be the content -> secondDiv
in DIV with id = 2 will be the content -> firstDiv
```

Thank you!

Comment: since you didn't mention javascript, do you need to actually switch the content or do you just need to switch the *appereance* order of your div?

Comment: I need switch the content (I can have 100 divs -> it means that must work for several divs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now used to `flex` in CSS like this:

```css
#divflex { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }

#two { order: 1; }
#one { order: 2; }
```

```html
<div id="divflex">



<div id="one">firstDiv</div>
<div id="two">secondDiv</div>

</div>
```

More about [flex order](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it without javascript or jquery, if use javascript, read the following code.

```js
var divOneContent = document.getElementById('one').innerHTML;
var divTwoContent = document.getElementById('two').innerHTML;

// move
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = divTwoContent;
document.getElementById('two').innerHTML = divOneContent;
```

```html
<div id="one">
  one
</div>
<div id="two">
  two
</div>
```

Comment: my solution is similar... anyway he said without javascript.. and that wont work

Answer (score 1):

Use `Flexbox` with direction `column-reverse`

```
body {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejmJxa)

Answer (score 0):

no way without javascript - you cant change the dom otherway

```
let div1 = document.getElemenentById("1");
let div2 = document.getElemenentById("2");
let div1Content = div1.innerHTML;
let div2Content = div2.innerHTML;
div1.innerHTML = div2Content;
div2.innerHTML = div1Content;
```

Comment: Was going to write somethign similar but then I read `without the jQuery or JavaScript`

Comment: jep - same... but no domchange without javascript - edited